# setValue для MultiSelect

Tags: webix, combo

как `WEBIX` задать значение для `multiselect`

```
view: "multiselect",
name: "systemId",
label:"Система",
align:"top",
 placeholder: 'Выберите систему',                                            
 options: {
        buttonText: "Выбрать",
        button: "Approve",
        url: "/adminstrator/ws/person/systemCombo",
        body: {
             template: "#value#"
         }
}
```

пытаюсь делать таким образом

```
$$('infoForm').elements['systemId'].setValue(personItem.hSystemId.id);
                                    $$('infoForm').elements['systemId'].refresh();
```

но безуспешно